# Brightness function keys not working in 12.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, brightness, keys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (info from `cat /etc/issue/`) on an Asus X401A

Kernel is: 3.8.0-31-generic

I've tried changing the `/etc/default/grub` file with the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor
```

and

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX"acpi_osi=linux
```

With no luck.

Any other ideas? I really want it fixing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually you have to replace that line with: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` not with those you have mentioned. Try it once and reply what happens..

Comment: Have you updated the grub with sudo grub-update?? (it's something a lot of new users forget doing)
Have you tried changing the brightness without the hotkeys of your asus (hotkeys don't work on some laptops without some work)
Also I assume you've closed your lines with the appropriate " but just to be save I'm asking you to check if you did this.

Comment: I'll try that now Saurav, thank you. Yes Arno I have closed lines with ". I can change the brightness in the brightness settings just not with function keys F5 and F6

Comment: I tried it Saurav but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Try this instead:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I did update grub after entering that information.

Comment: Did you restart your computer afterwards?

Comment: Yes. I added that line, updated grub then rebooted. It still doesn't work.